# Ereg_replace() is deprecated

Tags: php

Как текущий код переделать, что бы не выдавало ошибку

```
$return = trim(ereg_replace(' +', ' ', preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', '', strtolower($input))));
```

Ereg_replace() is deprecated

Comment: гугл первой же ссылкой дает официальную документацию http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ereg-replace.php   в которой на красном фоне сказано, что надо использовать preg_replace, т.к. ereg устарела

Comment: А все отличие preg от ereg в том, что регулярки должны быть в косых

Answer (score 1):

```
$replaces = array(
    '/^\s+|\s+$/'      => '',  // это вместо trim - убираем пробелы в начале и в конце
    '/ +/'             => ' ', // убираем повторяющиеся пробелы
    '/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/' => ''
);
$return = preg_replace(array_keys($replaces), $replaces, strtolower($input));
```